# Syntax Error - List Creating

Tags: list, syntax

I am trying to create a program where users enter a city and it prints the latitude and says whether it is above/below the equator. There is an error with ths list in Line one Next to London. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Capital_Cities = [("London"= 51.5), ("Paris" = 48.85), ("Canberra" = -35.3), ("Tokyo" = 35.68), ("Brasilia" = -15.78), ("Berlin"= 52.52), ("Buenos Aires" = -34.6), "Moscow" = 55.75, ("New Delhi" = 28.6), ("Beijing" = 39.9), ("Budapest" = 47.47), ("Brussels" = 50.85), ("Stockholm" = 59.32), ("Islamabad" = 33.72), ("Kuala Lumpur" = 3.13),("Helsinki" = 60.17), ("Oslo" = 59.95), ("Lusaka" = -15.42), ("Lima" = -12.03), ("Mexico City" = 19.43)]

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure what language you are using, I am going to use Python as an example.

What you need is probably a type of data structure called dictionary. In python, a dictionary looks like this, dic = {}.

So instead of you list of cities, the dictionary will looks like this,
Capital_Cities = {"London":51.5, "Paris":48.85, ..., "Lima": -12.03, "Mexico City":19.43}

In this case, you can easily refer any city by calling Capital_Cities[CityName]. If you call Capital_Cities[London], it will return 51.5.

I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks :) I am using Python

Comment: -  It didnt work, can you please attach more help as i am not very familiar with dictionaries

Comment: Capital_Cities = {'London':51.5, 'Paris':48.85}
If you call Capital_Cities['London'], it will return 51.5.
Sorry, my bad. I missed ' ' sign in the response.